# Custom IAuthorizationFilter injected with Ninject stops other ActionFilterAttribute from being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

In a project I'm working on there are two custom ActionFilterAttribute classes which are injected using ninjects BindFilter:

```
        kernel.BindFilter<LogErrorsAttribute>(FilterScope.Last, 0);
        kernel.BindFilter<CriticalErrorAttribute>(FilterScope.Last, 1);
```

These have been working fine.

I created a custom IAuthorizationFilter filter which is also injected using BindFilter:

```
        kernel.BindFilter<AuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, null).WhenActionMethodHas<Authorise>().WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorise>("Roles", n => n.Roles).WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Authorise>("Years", n => n.Years);
```

On it's own, this works fine too.

I just discovered that if I apply the Authorise tag to an action, the two custom ActionFilterAttribute classes are no longer called.

I'm stumped on why this would be occuring. My custom IAuthorizationFilter looks like this:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] RolesHaveAccessToApplication;

    public AuthorizationFilter()
    {
        //put roles which should allow user to see application, hardcoded for now, but later
        //this can be generated from the database
        var configRoles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationRoles"];

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(configRoles))
            throw new Exception("The ApplicationRoles value has not been defined in the web.config file.");

        RolesHaveAccessToApplication = configRoles.Split(',');

    }

    [Inject]
    public IUserServices userService { get; set; }

    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string Years { get; set; }


    protected bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;


        if(!Roles.HasContent() && !Years.HasContent())
        {
            return RolesHaveAccessToApplication.Any(role => RolesHaveAccessToApplication.Any(n => n == role));

        }

        var AuthenticatedUserRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        bool isAuthorised = false;

        //first, lets check against to see if the user has any roles related to the application
        isAuthorised = RolesHaveAccessToApplication.Any(role => AuthenticatedUserRoles.Any(n => n == role));

        //if they don't, we throw them to access denied page
        if (!isAuthorised)
            return false;

        #region CheckRoles
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles) && AuthenticatedUserRoles.HasContent())
        {
            var authRoles = Roles.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            isAuthorised = authRoles.Any(role => AuthenticatedUserRoles.Any(n => n == role));
        }
        #endregion

        #region CheckYears
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Years) && AuthenticatedUserRoles.HasContent())
        {


            if (AuthenticatedUserRoles.Any(n => n == "Student"))
            {
                var yearRoles = Years.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var user = userService.FetchUser(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    isAuthorised = yearRoles.Any(n => n == user.Year);
                }
            }

        }
        #endregion

        return isAuthorised;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext == null)
            throw new Exception("filtercontext is null");

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

            if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
                SetCachePolicy(filterContext);
            else
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);


    }

    protected void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext).Action("Denied", "Home", new {Area = ""}));// new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Home/Denied", View = new RazorView("Home") //ViewData = viewData }; 
        else
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

    }

    protected void SetCachePolicy(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
           ..snip..
    } 

}

//Used as a filter for actions, and ninject is configured to bind AuthorizationFilter to this
public class Authorise : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string Years { get; set; }
}
```

Any help with resolving this would be appreciated.

Edit:

This is one of the other filters:

```
public class CriticalErrorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IErrorServices ErrorService { private get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {            //if the request is an ajax request, we don't want a redirect to happen
        //the controller dealing with the ajax request can fetch the critical
        //errors and pass them back to the user for display
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var criticalErrors = ErrorService.FetchCriticalErrors();

            if (criticalErrors.HasContent())
            {
                var helper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                var url = helper.Action("Error", "Home", new { area = "" });

                filterContext.Controller.TempData["CriticalErrorList"] = criticalErrors;

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If a domain object couldnt be hydrated, it would log a critical error. This filter checks for such errors, if they occur it directs the user to an error page.

Solved:

It turns out Darin was correct! But the issue was being hidden by my configuration of my filters.
Firstly, I had [Authorise] on navigation items, and secondly I was binding the CriticalErrorAttribute to every action.
So each time a menu was built (welcome, left, nav, sub) - this filter was firing. At some point during this chain of filter calls, results were being applied to filterContext.Result - the later results hiding the earlier (correct) result.

To overcome this issue, I tweaked the BindFilter configuration line for CriticalErrorAttribute to this:

```
kernel.BindFilter<CriticalErrorAttribute>(FilterScope.Last, 0).When( (context, ad) =>
context.RouteData.DataTokens["action"] != null && context.RouteData.DataTokens["action"] !=
"Error" && context.RouteData.DataTokens["controller"] != "Navigation");
```

Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: What are your filter returning when the other filters do not execute?

Comment: I've updated my question with one of the other filters.

Comment: you did not answer my question.

Comment: The returned view of the domain model is null, so it's throwing an exception. The filter did catch such errors before the action was executed, displaying them on an error page, prior to the custom auth attribute being placed on actions.

Comment: this looks wrong "if (!AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext)) SetCachePolicy(filterContext);". Is the ! correct there?

Comment: Hi Wim, I'm not sure how that got there! I just checked and I must have taken it out of the live version after pasting it, but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
filterContext.Result = ...
```

you are assigning a result. And according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

> You can cancel filter execution in the OnActionExecuting and
>   OnResultExecuting methods by setting the Result property to a non-null
>   value. Any pending OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting filters will
>   not be invoked and the invoker will not call the OnActionExecuted
>   method for the canceled filter or for pending filters. The
>   OnActionExecuted filter for previously run filters will run. All of
>   the OnResultExecutingand OnResultExecuted filters will run.

Comment: Hi Darin, I'm only assigning a result if auth fails. So that code isn't being executed. To check, I removed those lines of code and the issue is still occuring.

Comment: I've added some text to the bottom of my question which might help.

Comment: Hi Darin, you were correct on this issue. It took a while to debug, but I've appended my solution to my answer.